# No Error in Redshift Copy command for loading ORC but the Redshift table is not updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, orc

I am loading ORC files present in an Amazon S3 bucket to an Amazon Redshift database using the `COPY` command.

The copy command runs successfully but the Redshift table isn't updated.
I am not able to catch any errors.

Copy command:

```
copy public."testairflow" 
from 's3://demofile/demo1.orc'  
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::****'
format as ORC;
```

Kindly tell where is the error?

Comment: It is possible that Redshift didn't think there was any data in the file. You could try reading the file using Amazon Redshift Spectrum or Amazon Athena to verify the format of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that when you give an inexisting S3 path, Redshift wll consider that there is no file there and will return a success.

Always make sure that your path is correct and hosted in the same region than your Redshift (it doesn't support cross-region COPY for colunar files).